# RSA and .PEM file Conversion to use in php

Tags: php, ssl, encryption, openssl, rsa

I generated my own RSA keys at 2048bits using a C++ library and I have all the keys in an array.
I mean N, E, D, p, q, dP, dQ, qInv.
I want to use them in php to decrypt an incoming message to my page.
The most suggested solution around is to use OpenSSL which needs a .pem file and cannot load my Keys in the plain format (including the CRT).

Here is an example of my public Modulus N

```
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
[HEX RSA - E-LEN 4]::00010001
```

The other elements of the key I keep them obviously secret.

If I try to convert them using the online conversion tools from XML to .PEM I format them in base64:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>n9ja0zZUR6+sB+ih0tcp3gmcbM/Thh9reOv1iMLNbi0vzoo2jfmVnpTpv0Y6wS4IS2nPdZH7SNT0aiXDNwd5vFf6jS9B5VB7bdx2flF0QmsTq1LuBrH6oDPeCCnu2jjInlGCOhIhTnb3I9CaJqczImpPZQs2ITBzAoippJt+ZRleN6ePgG0+0yLfvtgzVLYJzgiZk5fldHOJ12Mcp5U2kVwonif6+IIaRUz1ojjCHKD3g+QXfDh8q+4AtzNfLB7ltpEAwUMgkyw/lTwRpHYslkIS8JZmyN3mIsxOP9t5FUAl4ws4ZZHaNJmvwBBoD/lkjWZZbxWsq77s4I442Q4E5A==</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

I used this site to test it: https://superdry.apphb.com/tools/online-rsa-key-converter
which bases the conversion on BouncyCastle library.

The online tools they return me invalid parameter while if I use an OpenSSL generated file it works ok:

Plain N Key generated by OpenSSL:

```
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
```

base64 Encrypted

```
ALEiv6CC7jbfM/TK2ldvH16aZT25XJ3uz6SIY1B+6841bpN/eDqcWOXR7WDR+hl0PEtdaDD2hPehAOHLcDf4aqsQCoQNa2ORAIyeMALbXxNwFwcZ/frkxG/2rxo5il9/DJwAbex6KYxpcEDJE3XSpADtcdib2DshkEh+5uk5tSG/HpdJNWXka8QhYOmF8MHTdK2H12qNIFs+Y48bVE/JRvo0Vkx4NeM7cYe9S6shQFSj8FPgpMJP7+E66Il3Pc+wiynP//Jaz0huiPfaWUm/QTyJFgoyOkh06d8euWEITgjMwZAQKsQre+Dx1FT4080x1kVw1xpA88vVhyXwN3Dag5k=
```

XML Formatted for conversion:

```
<RSAKeyValue>
<Modulus>ALEiv6CC7jbfM/TK2ldvH16aZT25XJ3uz6SIY1B+6841bpN/eDqcWOXR7WDR+hl0PEtdaDD2hPehAOHLcDf4aqsQCoQNa2ORAIyeMALbXxNwFwcZ/frkxG/2rxo5il9/DJwAbex6KYxpcEDJE3XSpADtcdib2DshkEh+5uk5tSG/HpdJNWXka8QhYOmF8MHTdK2H12qNIFs+Y48bVE/JRvo0Vkx4NeM7cYe9S6shQFSj8FPgpMJP7+E66Il3Pc+wiynP//Jaz0huiPfaWUm/QTyJFgoyOkh06d8euWEITgjMwZAQKsQre+Dx1FT4080x1kVw1xpA88vVhyXwN3Dag5k=</Modulus>
<Exponent>AQAB</Exponent>
</RSAKeyValue>
```

Result

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsSK/oILuNt8z9MraV28f
XpplPblcne7PpIhjUH7rzjVuk394OpxY5dHtYNH6GXQ8S11oMPaE96EA4ctwN/hq
qxAKhA1rY5EAjJ4wAttfE3AXBxn9+uTEb/avGjmKX38MnABt7HopjGlwQMkTddKk
AO1x2JvYOyGQSH7m6Tm1Ib8el0k1ZeRrxCFg6YXwwdN0rYfXao0gWz5jjxtUT8lG
+jRWTHg14ztxh71LqyFAVKPwU+Ckwk/v4TroiXc9z7CLKc//8lrPSG6I99pZSb9B
PIkWCjI6SHTp3x65YQhOCMzBkBAqxCt74PHUVPjTzTHWRXDXGkDzy9WHJfA3cNqD
mQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----

And this is OK.

Does anybody understand why this is not working in my case?

Another point:
I exported OpenSSL N modulus Key and I noticed that it is made of 257 bytes instead of 256 and compared with two keypairs they both starts with 00 which is obviously too wrong.

The bottom line is how can I easily take my HEX plain keys values and encapsulte them into a PEM file or the way around how can I get the correct plain HEX keys values generated by OpenSSL and use them in my C Library (using the .PEM in php)?

[image]

Added:

Given that this is the RSA Key structure:

```
RSAPrivateKey ::= SEQUENCE {
          version           Version,
          modulus           INTEGER,  -- n
          publicExponent    INTEGER,  -- e
          privateExponent   INTEGER,  -- d
          prime1            INTEGER,  -- p
          prime2            INTEGER,  -- q
          exponent1         INTEGER,  -- d mod (p-1)
          exponent2         INTEGER,  -- d mod (q-1)
          coefficient       INTEGER,  -- (inverse of q) mod p
          otherPrimeInfos   OtherPrimeInfos OPTIONAL
      }
```

If I make an inspection with ASN.1 Editor it clearly shows me:
That the Key length of N is 257 Bytes instead of 256 and prime1, prime2 and exponent1 are made of 129 bytes instead of 128.

Super confusing for me....

Comment: You probably forget that in ASN1 everything is encoded as TLV that is each content starts with the type, then its length, then the payload itself.

Comment: Check your key generation, your modulus is even.

Comment: @Topaco.       The N modulus with 128 bytes is the correct length. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I mean that your modulus 0x9FD8...04E4 is divisible by 2.

Comment: Since the modulus is the product of two prime numbers (both not equal to 2), it should be odd. So probably there is a problem with your key generation.

Comment: @Topaco you are right but the RSA encryption and decryption works on my side. I generated new keys and the N is now passing the XML but now I have other values failing.
This thing is a nightmare!

Comment: *...I have other values failing...* is not very precise. Does this refer to the key? If you are not sure if the key data is correct, you might want to post the *complete* data to a *test* key (not a productive one) so it can be checked. By the way, the leading 0x00 values are not problematic (and are a consequence of representing signed big-endian values as two's complement, s. [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/45158) for more details).

Comment: @Topaco here I paste a log of a round of encryption and decryption https://pastebin.com/raw/uVgyALcE here you will find all test keys.

The point is that I can easily generate keys the library I am using is www.di-mgt.com.au/bigdigits.html and I guess I should focus more on Endianess.

I guess my keys are generated correctly but something is wrong when I print them our or such. 

Have a look at my copy and paste.

Comment: Something seems to be wrong with your key generation. p*q and n are different (both when interpreted as little endian and as big endian).

Comment: MY BAD.... I am still investigating how the library converts Bytes. 
So far I can now manually generate Key Pair and convert it to PEM but my Printf is for some reasons wrong.

Once I discover what the problem was I will post it right away